# How to add modules in test for imports-loader configuration

Tags: jquery, webpack, mcustomscrollbar, imports-loader

As I am converting legacy webapp to webpack based application, it uses [mCustomScrollbar](https://github.com/malihu/malihu-custom-scrollbar-plugin).
As per documentation of mCustomScrollbar, to run with webpack need to use imports-loader. But syntax given in doc is compatible with older version of webpack, not with latest.

And as per [doc](https://webpack.js.org/loaders/imports-loader/) of imports-loader, I am not able to add `malihu-custom-scrollbar-plugin` to `test` of `modules-rules`.

```
{
    test: /jquery-mousewheel/, /* This works fine */
    use: [{
            loader: "imports-loader",
            options: {
                imports: {
                    moduleName: "jquery",
                    name: "$"
                },
                wrapper: "window",
                additionalCode:
                    "var define = false;"
            }
        }]
},
{
    test: /malihu-custom-scrollbar-plugin/, /* Not working */
    use: [{
            loader: "imports-loader",
            options: {
                imports: {
                    moduleName: "jquery",
                    name: "$"
                },
                wrapper: "window",
                additionalCode:
                    "var define = false;"
            }
        }]
}
```

Gives below errors,

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/malihu-custom-scrollbar-plugin/jquery.mCustomScrollbar.css 8:6
Module parse failed: 'import' and 'export' may only appear at the top level (8:6)
File was processed with these loaders:
 * ./node_modules/imports-loader/dist/cjs.js
```

My vendor.js looks like below,

```
...
import "malihu-custom-scrollbar-plugin/jquery.mCustomScrollbar.css";
...

import $ from "jquery";
window.jQuery = jQuery;
window.$ = $;

...
require("jquery-mousewheel")($);
require("malihu-custom-scrollbar-plugin")($);
...
```

So how to get this working and how to combine two modules in same imports-loader, in my case `jquery-mousewheel` and `malihu-custom-scrollbar-plugin`.

Answer (score 1):

As `.css` file of mCustomScrollbar was creating issue with webpack's other loaders, added imports-loader configuration inline to `vendor.js` and removed from webpack config file.

Now `vendor.js` looks like below,

```
...
import "malihu-custom-scrollbar-plugin/jquery.mCustomScrollbar.css";
...

import $ from "jquery";
window.jQuery = jQuery;
window.$ = $;

...
require("imports-loader?wrapper=window&!jquery-mousewheel");
require("imports-loader?wrapper=window&!malihu-custom-scrollbar-plugin");
...
```

With this mCustomScrollbar got working, let me know if there is better way to do it or this is correct approach.